# jquery select div below parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few divs set up like so:

```
 <div class="menu_options">
    <div class="parent_div">input field</div>
    <div class="children_div">
        <div class='something">field</div>
        <div class="something_else">field</div>
    </div>
 </div>

<div class="menu_options">
    <div class="parent_div">input field</div>
    <div class="children_div">
        <div class='something">field</div>
        <div class="something_else">field</div>
    </div>
 </div>

<div class="menu_options">
    <div class="parent_div">input field</div>
    <div class="children_div">
        <div class='something">field</div>
        <div class="something_else">field</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

in jquery i am doing

```
        $('.parent_options').each(function() {
            $(this).click(function() {

            });
        });
```

right now $(this) is giving me the parent_div that i clicked on and I need to be able to move down to the children_div and hide the entire children_div. Any ideas. I know in prototype i used a down function but not sure if jquery has it.

Comment: In the javascript, is the selector supposed to be '.parent_div', or '.menu_options'? What you have ('.parent_options') doesn't exist.

Comment: Would anyon know how to do it if i was inside the parent div and clicking on a input field with a class name required. and would need to get out of the current div and move down to the children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to hide `.children_div` after clicking on `.parent_div` use

```
  $('.parent_div').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings(".children_div").hide();
  });
```

Demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/FBYah/)

Comment: Would you know how to do it if i was inside the parent div and clicking on a input field with a class name required. and would need to get out of the current div and move down to the children

Comment: @Yevo: `$('.parent_div input.classname').click(function() { $(this).siblings('.children_div').hide() });`

Comment: As a post-script to the avoid, rather than using `click` as you suggest, you'd be better to use `focus`, to handle tabbed access.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.parent_div').each(function() {
            $(this).click(function() {
        $(this).next().hide();
            });
        });​
```

Comment: I agree that is not the best answer, I took his exact question and gave him an answer to match his request. He asked for something similar to Prototypes down function

Comment: Theodore i tried the first function you mentioned but its returning empty object

Answer (score 0):

If you're binding the function to all `.menu-options`, there's no need for `each()`. This should work if I understood your query properly:

```
$('.parent_div').click(function() {  
    $(this).siblings('.children_div').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try  `.next()`

```
 $( this ).next( ".tb-contents'" ).show();
```

This will work.

Thanks